# Error: No tidy method for objects of class nlsModel

Tags: tidy, broom

I have an issue with the package 'broom' and the functions tidy() and augment() when trying to apply them to nlsModel. I have seen the similar issues on the forum already for other models, but none of the solutions proposed worked for me.

I am trying to do something similar as what is proposed on this link:

https://padpadpadpad.github.io/post/bootstrapping-non-linear-regressions-with-purrr/

I have a problem running the following lines:

```
# get parameters ####
params_boot <- fit_boots %>%
               unnest(fit %>% map(tidy)) %>%
               ungroup()

# get predictions
preds_boot <- fit_boots %>%
              unnest(fit %>% map(augment)) %>%
              ungroup()
```

The error message is showing:

```
Error: No tidy method for objects of class nlsModel
```

Any idea what to do?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem - it worked before but now doesn't. I found a work around with this:

```
params_boot <- map(fit_boots$fit, tidy) %>%
map_df(as_tibble) %>%
ungroup() %>%
mutate(boot_num = rep(c(1:nboots), each = 6)) #this part is clunky nboots is number of boots
```